# How to reshape any data-frame to a 2-columns data-frame, with the (repeated) column names in the first and the corresponding values in the second?

Tags: r

How can one reshape data-frame like this:

```
x1  x2  x3  x4
1   1   5   6
1   2   3   5
2   1   6   1
2   2   2   4
```

to:

```
x1  1   
x1  1
x1  2
x1  2
x2  1
.
.
.
```

I have read many posts (like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5890584/how-to-reshape-data-from-long-to-wide-format)) but I could not figure this out.

Comment: `data.frame(nm = rep(names(df), each = nrow(df)), value = unlist(df), row.names = NULL)`

Comment: This questions is not useful. You said "I have read many posts but I could not figure this out" but a simple "R + reshape" search on this website brings on this page: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5890584/how-to-reshape-data-from-long-to-wide-format, which I assume contains your answer. (And if it does not, you have to explain why.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to reshape data from long to wide format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5890584/how-to-reshape-data-from-long-to-wide-format)

Comment: @Arthur this is not unstacking problem. thanks for that post but not really useful

Comment: OK, and sorry for being rude. Maybe the title of your question is misleading...

Comment: @Arthur you can always modify the title and the question. I am always happy to learn and I appreciate the time you have put and looked at my question. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using `stack`

```
stack(df)
   values ind
1       1  x1
2       1  x1
3       2  x1
4       2  x1
5       1  x2
6       2  x2
7       1  x2
8       2  x2
9       5  x3
10      3  x3
11      6  x3
12      2  x3
13      6  x4
14      5  x4
15      1  x4
16      4  x4
```

For plot

```
df$ind=as.character(df$ind)
boxplot(values~ind,data=df)
```

Comment: @nik, just do `boxplot(df)`

Comment: @nik edit and alos you can try the method d.b mentioned ~ 
:-)

Answer (score 1):

Using the `melt()` command would likely be the best solution assuming you've got an ID column as well. Check out this [link](https://www.statmethods.net/management/reshape.html) for a further explanation.

```
newdf <- reshape2::melt(df, id="id").
```

If you don't have an ID already you can make rownames an ID column and then drop it later.

```
df$id <- rownames(df)
newdf <- melt(df, id="id").
newdf$id <- NULL
```

Also, it's bad form to ask further questions in the comments but run `?boxplot()` in the console and it should be fairly straightforward.